# Transaction Isolation Level Scopes

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, isolation-level

What are the scoping rules for transaction isolation levels in SQL Server 2005? I know what the different levels mean, but not how to properly apply them outside of a manually run script. I can't find a guide for practical use in production-quality code.

Obviously, the scope begins when you use a command like this:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
```

But where does it end? If I set the iso level in a stored procedure and then that proc calls another, does the nested proc inherit it? Even better, if I escalate the iso level inside the nested proc is it going to carry back out into the calling proc? Do transaction commands like BEGIN TRAN, ROLLBACK, and COMMIT make any differences?

When a stored proc is called by an application or an agent job do the isolation level changes persist in some way? Do I always have to revert to the default READ COMMITTED at the end of each proc?

I would test it in different situations but I don't know how to read what the current isolation level is set to.

Comment: The fact that the scope of this goes beyond the current transaction (and, due to connection pooling, beyond the current "session") can burn you. See [this post](http://www.codeducky.org/mysterious-deadlocks-leaking-isolation-levels/) I wrote on the subject.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Run the following and see for yourself:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.KeepsIsolation
AS
BEGIN
PRINT 'Inside sproc that does not change isolation level';
DBCC USEROPTIONS;
END
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.ChangesIsolation
AS
BEGIN
PRINT 'Inside sproc that changes isolation level';
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
DBCC USEROPTIONS;
END
GO
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;
DBCC USEROPTIONS;
EXEC dbo.KeepsIsolation;
DBCC USEROPTIONS;
EXEC dbo.ChangesIsolation;
-- demonstrates that isolation level restored to REPEATABLE READ after exiting the procedure
    DBCC USEROPTIONS;
```

Comment: So it looks like the parent proc doesn't get affected by changes to the iso level within the child proc, but the child proc inherits the parent's iso level as the default.

Answer (score 17):

From [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx)

> If you issue SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL **in a stored procedure** or
>   trigger, when the object returns control the isolation level **is reset
>   to the level in effect when the object was invoked**. For example, if
>   you set REPEATABLE READ in a batch, and the batch then calls a stored
>   procedure that sets the isolation level to SERIALIZABLE, the isolation
>   level setting reverts to REPEATABLE READ when the stored procedure
>   returns control to the batch.

Answer (score 15):

`DBCC USEROPTIONS` will display the current isolation level, along with all of the other SET options.

Answer (score 4):

From books on line

> Only one of the TRANSACTION ISOLATION
>   LEVEL options can be set at a time,
>   and it remains set for that connection
>   until it is explicitly changed. This
>   becomes the default behavior unless an
>   optimization option is specified at
>   the table level in the FROM clause of
>   the statement.

Comment: However, the accepted answer demonstrates that this is not true - changing the the ISOLATION level within a stored proc does not change the level for a calling stored proc.

Either the docs are wrong or I've misunderstood.

Comment: Agree with the previous comment. While I appreciate the quoting of the BOL comment, this seems to be at odds with the accepted answer.

Comment: Actually it is correct. It also is NOT COMPLETE. Now, if you ignore the exception given in the documentation (check quote from Andrey) then - ah - yeah, this is the type of bad answer that one posts.

Answer (score 2):

Isolation level does not roll back with the transaction.

Isolation level stays current even if you call into procedures and functions.

Answer (score 1):

Please note there is an issue with scope of TRANSACTION LEVELS and SqlServer 2012 or earlier when high performance ADO.NET Connection Pooling is used where this can actually persist across closing of the connection:

[SQL Server: Isolation level leaks across pooled connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9851415/sql-server-isolation-level-leaks-across-pooled-connections)

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/916b3d8a-c464-4ad5-8901-6f845a2a3447/sql-server-2014-reseting-isolation-level?forum=sqldatabaseengine